# Set auto resizing mask to gradient background

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, autoresizingmask

I have a background on the homescreen of my app which  want to expand to fill the screen when it is rotated though I have tried to give it autoresizingmasks though it won't let as it is a CALayer. At the moment when you resize the screen there is a big white space on the right left by where the gradient was

Here is the code I am using to initialize the gradient:

```
UIColor *highColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:128.0f/255.0f blue:214.0f/255.0f alpha:1.000];
UIColor *lowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:5.0f/255.0f green:69.0f/255.0f blue:150.0f/255.0f alpha:1.000];
gradientBackground = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[gradientBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
[gradientBackground setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[highColor CGColor], (id)[lowColor CGColor], nil]];
backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];
[backgroundLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
[backgroundLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[backgroundLayer addSublayer:gradientBackground];
backgroundObject = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundObject];
[[backgroundObject layer] insertSublayer:backgroundLayer atIndex:0];
[backgroundObject setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Any advice as to how to fix this issue will be muchly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work out a way around using a CALayer and just set the background of the view to an image of a gradient like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-gradient.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you embed the layer in a view, then set the resizing mask on the view? You could subclass both UIView and CALayer, then implement the view's `+layerClass` method to return your layer subclass and use the layer subclass to draw the gradient.

Comment: How would I do that. I will post how I am doing the gradient